# Date format in mongodb/mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js, express, mongoose

When I create a date in javascript it is in zulu, when I save it in my mongodb via mongoose it is transformed to UTC (its keeps the same time value, but the timezone is changed). I'd like it to stay in zulu when saved, how can I set this option in mongoose ?

thanks

Comment: I'm just curious: what is the practical difference between Zulu (GMT) and UTC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB stores all DateTimes in UTC. Any local times you supply are converted to UTC when stored in the database. The recommended approach is to always convert DateTime values to UTC yourself before storing them in the database, that way you are in full control.

Resources:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-185 
[Dealing with how MongoDB stores DateTime when used with Service Locator Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438219/dealing-with-how-mongodb-stores-datetime-when-used-with-service-locator-pattern)